# A question about Schwartz space

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces

In page 250 of Real Analysis by Folland, it is stated that if $f$ belongs to the Schwartz space, then $\partial^{\alpha}f \in L^p$ for all $\alpha$ and all $p\in[1,\infty]$.

I think it is true for $p<1$ and here is my argument.

$$|\partial^{\alpha}f(x)|\leq C_N(1+|x|)^{-N}$$ for all $N$.

We need to show that $(1+|x|)^{-Np}\in L^1$ for some $N$.

If $B=\{x:|x|<2\}$, then $$(1+|x|)^{-Np}\leq 2^{-Np}|x|^{-Np}.$$ on $B^c.$ So for $N>n/p$, $(1+|x|)^{-Np} \in L^1(B^c)$.

On the other hand, it's clear that $(1+|x|)^{-Np}\in L^1(B).$

Therefore, $f\in L^p$ also for $p<1$.

So why does not the book state it for $p<1$?

Comment: Apart from the mistake pointed out in the answer below I would say that the case $p<1$ is not interesting. It is true that the result holds for $p <1$ but the author doesn't care!

Answer (score 0):

I think that to say $(1+|x|)^{-Np} \leq 2^{-Np}|x|^{-Np}$ is to say that 
$2|x| \leq 1+|x|$, i.e. $|x| \leq 1$, is that what you meant to say?

Comment: No, on $B^c$ we know that $|x|\geq 1$. So $1+|x|\leq |x|+|x|=2|x|$.

Comment: Now we are taking the reciprocal of these terms so the inequality will switch direction